# Magento 2 : Rest Api For Customer Login

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0, rest-api

I am creating an app for Magento 2 but there is no any API for a customer to check if user/customer is authenticated or not.
Followed : http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html#/

But there is not any solution.

Comment: I have tried by that way @Randall Anthony Bondoc, but its not working for me with postman, can you please explain me in detail how i can use customer login authentication with postman with inbuilt api?

Answer (score 4):

you can use the authenticate function in accountmanagerinterface. in your webapi.xml file include this code.

```
<route url="/V1/customers/authenticate/:email/:password" method="GET">
    <service class="Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface" method="authenticate"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

you can call this via curl in php.

```
    $userData = array("username" => "your_username", "password" => "your_password");
    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch); 

    $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/magento/index.php/rest/V1/customers/authenticate/".
        "roni_cost@example.com". //username/email
        "/".
        "roni_cost3@example.com" //password
        );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    echo($result);
```

Comment: this code working for me thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Randall i am getting below error 
{"message":"Request does not match any route.","trace":null}
what to do now to solve this error. Please suggest me.

Comment: hello i am also getting error Request does not match any route. can you help me regarding this

Answer (score 4):

You should use this API:
integrationCustomerTokenServiceV1:

Interface providing token generation for Customers
POST /V1/integration/customer/toke

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-token.html

Answer (score 0):

For creating an App in MAgento 2, you can follow the REST API for a customer to authenticate.

**For Customer Token:** Magento grants access to resources with the anonymous or self permission.

Use the API:
Endpoint: POST /rest/<store_code>/V1/integration/customer/token

Soap: integrationCustomerTokenServiceV1

For full details please check:
https://www.cloudways.com/blog/magento-2-rest-api/